# Searchview interfering with other buttons

Tags: android

I have a searchview next to a filter button, but ever time I click on the other button the searchview also listens and expands, here is a snippet of the before [How the buttons are positioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO8iq.png)

[When filter button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBz8a.png)

and here is my menu layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_sort"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter_list_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/Sort"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

my Java code:

```
    @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activty_ecommerce_sort, menu);
    SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    final SearchView search = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    search.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    search.setActivated(true);
    search.setQueryHint("Search");
    search.onActionViewExpanded();
    search.setIconified(false);
    search.clearFocus();
    search.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    int id = menuItem.getItemId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.action_sort:
            filterDailog();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
}
```

Anyone have an idea where the issue is?

Comment: Removing `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"` from action_sort item would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"` from sort item.

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_sort"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter_list_black_24dp"
android:title="@string/Sort"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
```

instead of;

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_sort"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter_list_black_24dp"
android:title="@string/Sort"
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
```

Comment: this is embarrassing, thank you, I did not see this coming.

Comment: No problem. You can check the answer as the correct one.